# How to use Scale and Extrude together?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to create this shape. I don't understand how does it work. If I use E+S I can't get the faces forming the perimeter with an angle less than 90°?
[image]

Comment: Not sure if it's clear, but you cant really do it all in one go, it's a two step procedure. First you extrude, finish the extrusion only then scale it down.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with insetting the faces. First select the faces you want to extrude. Then hit <kbd>I</kbd> button to bring Inset operator. In the operator panel, thickness value changes the scale and depth value you changes the extrusion depth.

[image]