# I'm trying to extrude this and it won't come out the right way

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to follow this tutorial, and when it gets to the point of pulling the Z axis down, my points goes straight down and don't curve.

The tutorial is on left, and mine is on the right. Could it be because his blender version is older (roughly 5 years older) than mine? The tutorial is [YouTube - Absolute Beginners Blender 3D #16 Tutor](https://youtu.be/gO0L3WCgemE?t=179).

[image: Screenshots of Z axis - Tutorial and OP]

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67868/how-to-use-scale-and-extrude-together/67872

Comment: In the video he did not extrude, all he did was move the selected edges down along the Z axis.

Comment: Well, yeah, sorry that's what I meant, but it still doesn't do as he does it.

Comment: Can you please upload your file via this page and add it to your post?
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple, Its just the Fact that you are adding or creating new faces by extruding. However this guy did not extrude he just grabbed the selected edges and dragged them down along the Z axis. He might have also extruded down the outside and then just scaled the lower ring. But just remember Extruding adds faces, He only Moved faces.

Comment: To extrude press **E** drag down on the Z axis, then press **S** to scale and drag the mouse .